# Программа не завершает работу

Tags: java

Мне нужно циклически сдвигать символы, после ряда таких сдвигов должна получится реверснутая строка. Например:
caba -> acba->abca->abac
Нужно подсчитать кол-во таких сдвигов, но что-то не так :

```
public static void main(String args[]) {
    int N = scanner.nextInt();
    String s = scanner.next();
    StringBuffer reverse = new StringBuffer(s);
    StringBuffer sb = new StringBuffer(s);
    reverse = reverse.reverse();
    System.out.print(reverse);
    System.out.println(sb);
    int cnt = 0;
    while (!(sb.equals(reverse))) {
        for (int i = 0; i < N - 1; i++) {
            char t = sb.charAt(0);
            System.out.println(i);
            sb = sb.deleteCharAt(i);
            sb = sb.insert(i + 1, t);
            cnt++;
            System.out.println(sb);
        }
    }
    System.out.println(cnt);

}
```

Comment: если что у StringBuffer equals не переопределён... Так что думаю вы меня поняли)

Comment: Вывод в `System.out.println(sb);` ожидаемый? Или не соответствует `sb.equals(reverse)`?

Comment: @pavel, у StringBuffer equals сравнивает по ссылкам, а не значению? А StringBuilder?

Comment: @gil9red Да, как и у Object. Чтобы сравнивать строку извлекать надо в любом случае. Но тут я бы советовал вообще не менять строку. Остальной код конечно тут тоже неправильный, но вопрос - почему зависает)

Comment: *нужно циклически сдвигать символы ... Например: caba -> acba->abca->abac* Я вижу попарный обмен, а не циклический сдвиг. И реверсирование после этих обменов - чисто случайное, за счёт того, что первый и третий символы совпадают. А вообще это обычная сортировка пузырьком, только без сравнений.

Comment: Как тогда привести это в рабочее состояние?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Я исправила ошибки в программе. И получился такой вариант:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.print("Введите исходную строку: ");
    String s = scanner.next();
    StringBuilder reverse = new StringBuilder(s);
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder(s);
    reverse.reverse();
    System.out.println("Исходная строка: " + sb);
    System.out.println("Целевая строка: " + reverse);
    int cnt = 0;
    String revStr = reverse.toString();
    while (!(sb.toString().equals(revStr))) {
        for (int i = 0; i < sb.length() - 1; i++) {
            char t = sb.charAt(i);
            sb.deleteCharAt(i);
            sb.insert(i + 1, t);
            cnt++;
            System.out.println("Промежуточный результат: " + sb);
        }
    }
    System.out.println("Количество сдвигов: " + cnt);
}
```

Результат работы:

```
Введите исходную строку: caba
Исходная строка: caba
Целевая строка: abac
Промежуточный результат: acba
Промежуточный результат: abca
Промежуточный результат: abac
Количество сдвигов: 3
```

Но нужно понимать, что подобным образом невозможно реверсировать строку. В вашем примере это получается только потому, что 1й и 3й символы совпадают. Если ввести строку с разными символами, то условие цикла while никогда не выполнится и программа зациклится.

Comment: Нужно, чтоб код был универсальным. Переписала так, но ответа так и нет

Comment: public static void main(String args[]) {
  int N = scanner.nextInt();
  String s = scanner.next();
  char[] arr = s.toCharArray();
  int cnt=0;
  String RV="";
   StringBuilder reverse = new StringBuilder(s);
   reverse=reverse.reverse();
   for (int i=0; i<arr.length;i++) {
    RV+=reverse.charAt(i);
    
   }
   System.out.println(RV);
   char []REV = RV.toCharArray();
   
   while (arr!=REV) {
   for (int i=0; i<arr.length-1;i++) {
    char tem = arr[i];
    arr[i]=arr[i+1];
    arr[i+1]=tem;
    cnt++;
   }
   }
   

   
   System.out.println(cnt);
  }
 }

Comment: Анастасия, я не совсем поняла, что значит код должен быть универсальным? Можете написать здесь полностью условия задачи? Нужны именно попарные перестановки, или нужно полностью развернуть строку с помощью цикла? Напишите что нужно, и я постараюсь помочь

Comment: У вас в коде (предыдущий комментарий) в условии цикла while сравниваются два массива. Так их нельзя сравнивать. Поэтому и зацикливается программа. Эту строку нужно написать так:                     `while (!Arrays.equals(arr, REV)) {`. Так будет работать